# When are Google drive and Google docs indexed?

Tags: google-drive, google-search

I have published my doc as *Public on the Web -- Anyone on the Internet can find and view* a long time ago.

But, when I search for the pieces of my published document, Google result is empty. Should I try Bing search?

When does Google search index the Google Docs and Google Drive? If Google does not index the doc then what is the difference between *Public on the web* and *Anyone with link can access*?

Comment: The mysteries of the Googlebot are legion, and it is not for us mere mortals to know. Seriously, though, have you submitted the URL to Google to _be_ indexed?

Comment: No. I am sure that google knows about the documetns hosted on its drive. If you know that bot is needed or explicit indexing request, you may form that as the answer.

Comment: I'm interested in this question from the other perspective. I'd like a page to be accessible on the web so a user load it with their web browser but have it not generally accessible to others. I know they support "anyone with the link" access but in that mode they won't serve it as a web page.

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive hosted files are not being crawled just because they are public files. The URL of the each file should be included in a website that is being crawled or should be submitted directly to be indexed.

In my humble opinion, the easiest way for a small number of URLs, is to share publicly the URL of your files in tools like Google+, Facebook, Twitter, etc. To learn the "pro" way, see [Are you on Google? - Webmasters Tools Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34397?hl=en) 
For something in the middle, see [Google My Business](http://www.google.com/business/).

Regarding the difference between, sharing with Anyone in the web and Publishing to the web, the first gives access to the original version, the second to a separate web version, without real time features, the Google Editors tool bar, etc. For further details see [Visibility of documents, spreadsheets, and presentations published to the web](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=en).